# VBA: select first cell after data is filtered

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I am using the record function to create a macro off of keystrokes. I need to find the first cell in column C and then set it to equal what is in column A. Then I need it to fill down to the bottom of all filtered cells.

```
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$N").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
         "=*total*", Operator:=xlAnd
Range("C5").Select
```

In the above example, my filtered data starts at C5, but on a different data set it starts at C3 and skips straight to C5.

I am unsure of what to try as this is new to me. I am thinking xlDown could be useful.